# Definition of simultaneous use on Windows 10 RDP

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, license

I use Remote Desktop on Windows 10 frequently. The remote machine is set up as a PC (not a server). Recently, the mechanism for switching between remote users has stopped working.

Up to now, the behaviour was like this:

- One user is logged on to the remote machine over RDP.
- Another user tries to connect. They get a message, like "The remote machine is in use, do you want to press on?"
- If the new user clicks Yes, the logged-on user gets a warning, like "Another user wants to log on, do you allow this?" (and Yes/No buttons).
- If the logged-on user does not respond within a certain time, the second user is connected, and the first user's connection is broken.
- The first user's session is pushed into the background, not terminated. When the second user logs off or breaks the connection, the first user can log on and pick up the work from where they left.

But recently, the behaviour has suddenly changed. The second user does not see the "machine in use" message, and the logged-on user does not get the warning message. The second user sees the connection window for a short period, but at the point where the "machine in use" message should appear, the window just closes with no error message.

The effect is that the remote machine is blocked - if a user forgets to log out, the machine is inaccessible for everyone else. All the users in our group are only users, without Admin privileges.

My service helpdesk says that it is technically possible to fix the behaviour, but they refuse to do it because they claim that this would violate the Windows License Terms: "you are not allowed to (...) make the software available for simultaneous use by multiple users over a network, (...)".

So the question is: When only one user can be connected at the same time, is this "simultaneous use by multiple users"? Or is our use case actually legal according to the license?

Comment: have you checked to see if the "Fast User Switching" feature in windows is still turned on?

Comment: No - I have no Admin rights, and the Helpdesk could have done that. What I need is to know if they are correct in claiming that our user case violates the licence. If that is correct, I do not want to continue the practice, but I don't want to live with this trouble if it is not necessary.

Comment: The response you have received sounds like one I would give if I had purposefully made a group policy change to disable the behavior you described.  **Your IT staff is correct that only a single user (at a time) can use a consumer version of Windows**  Windows Server allows multiple users to be logged in with the proper licensing.  What I suspect and you are not able to verify since your NOT an Administrator is that a group policy has been changed and your IT staff simply doesn't want to indicate that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows license allows multi-user usage, as long as only one user-session is active at a time.

This is evident when you consider that Windows
has the "Switch user" action for changing the active session,
with no limit on the number of logged-in sessions.

Your past usage of Windows was consistent with the above scenario,
so there was no license violation.

The argument by your IT does not hold water. Most likely, they don't
know what they did to cause this change and are not admitting the fact.

Comment: +1 especially because of that last paragraph. Sounds like time to look for a new IT service.